# How can I view the state of a widget in flutter using dart dev tools

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to view the state that my widgets have in dev tools but all I see is the name of the state object and hash symbol with a 5 digit number. Is there anyway of seeing what exactly is in the state?